# Installing laravel suddenly some json file cannot be downloaded

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php

I typed `create-project laravel/laravel "foldername"` and got this message:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "http://packagist.org/p/illuminate/console%241d2f57f687204b9a57e5848fe9f49e79bc2fb7ed0cafc6d1387ad4760a1b155c.json"
>   file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

What's this for? I already got the laravel structure files but i don't want to continue without knowing whats with this error.

Update:
composer.json content under my laravel folder structure

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

}

Comment: add the composer.json content here

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi updated the content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this on your composer:

```
"repositories": [
    {
         "type": "composer", 
         "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    { "packagist": false }
]
```

and run **composer update** once again. If not then run `composer self-update`

Comment: composer:update command not found

when i run composer self-update,

"You are already using composer version 1.6.2 (stable channel)."

Comment: What does this do? Removing packagist from the sources and adding it again looks fishy....

Comment: in which file do you add this ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Linux. It prioritized ipv4 over ipv6.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
```

Comment: But why? Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: I can't "explain" it, but it seems packagist has problems with IPv6

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4142

Answer (score 1):

You need php curl module for this to work properly.

Check if you have php-curl with `php -m`

if Curl is not present on the list,  install it with (debian) `apt install php***-curl` replacing *** with your php version

`apt install php7.4-curl` works for debian with php 7.4 installed.

Try again after installing the curl php module and voilá